# WebRTC p2p connection without ICE servers

Tags: xmpp, strophe, libjingle

I am trying out the strophejingle example at jingle-interop (https://github.com/legastero/jingle-interop-demos/tree/gh-pages/strophejingle) which uses httpbind and the google open source ICE server "stun:stun.l.google.com:19302" to establish a peer-to-peer connection. I was thinking, whether is it possible to establish the connection without using ICE servers, if I am planning to use the example in a LAN? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can try passing an empty ICE servers config to RTCPeerConnection() API, that is no STUN or TURN server. In StropheJingle there is an ice_config options which contains that config.